# want to fix contact form till we are in that particular section

Tags: javascript, html, css, user-interface, position

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HvhEK.png)

Want to fix right side form till we are in that particular section (Course Curriculum).
any kind of help will be appreciated.

Comment: Please, add code snippet if you wont help.

Comment: you want to fix it? in what way is it broken?

Comment: No it's not broken , i want form must be visible till user viewing that section

Comment: hey @DimaVak not able to add code snippet , its taking too much space.

Comment: @JaromandaX i mean till user scrolling that section form  must me visible to user.

Comment: oh, you want its position fixed, sorry, misunderstood the context

Answer (score -2, accepted):

you can use the help of CSS sticky property

```
<div class="form-container">
 <div>other content</div>
 <div class="form">form</div>
</div>

<div class="other-container">
</div>

<style>
  .form-container{
   height: 150vh;
   background: #f1f1f1;
   position: relative;
   display: flex;
   justify-content: space-between;
  }
  .form{
    background: pink;
    width: 30vw;
    position: -webkit-sticky;
    position: sticky;
    right: 0;
    top: 10vh;
    height: 50vh;
  }
  .other-container{
   height: 150vh;
  }
</style>
```

Comment: sounds good, but as i am using bootstrap, text content is in col-9 and form is in col-3
and above that container which is position relative.

Comment: that doesn't matter, you can override col-3 position to sticky and parent of col-9 & col-3 to   relative

Comment: yeah you are right, but still trying to figure out, how i can achieve this, hope this codepen will clear the picture

https://codepen.io/amjayesh07/pen/JjYemZW